# Creating a List(Of) or Index to variable in structure group

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

`Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger` is the amount of cards of each particular card a player has in my game.

`Player1handgroup` has 28 indexes. The game has 5 players.

At the moment I currently have

```
Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger
Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2
Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3
Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4
Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5
```

representing each player in the game.

Code wise everytime I deal with a different player I have to repeat the same code often in order for it to work with the correct player.

I was wondering if it is possible to add an index to the Quantity integer or dynamically add a number to the end of quantity integer representing each player so I can clean up my code.

```
Structure Group
        Public CardNameString, CardType As String
        Public QuantityInteger2, QuantityInteger3, QuantityInteger4, QuantityInteger5, DamageInteger, ID, HitPoints As Integer
        Public QuantityInteger() As Integer
    End Structure

Private Sub LunchMoneyMainForm_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

DeckGroup(0).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(1).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(2).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(3).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(4).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(5).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(6).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(7).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(8).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(9).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(10).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(11).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(12).QuantityInteger(0) = 8
    DeckGroup(13).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(14).QuantityInteger(0) = 10
    DeckGroup(15).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(16).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(17).QuantityInteger(0) = 8
    DeckGroup(18).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(19).QuantityInteger(0) = 8
    DeckGroup(20).QuantityInteger(0) = 1
    DeckGroup(21).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(22).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(23).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(24).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(25).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(26).QuantityInteger(0) = 4
    DeckGroup(27).QuantityInteger(0) = 1


 Private Sub StartButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

For StartHands = 0 To 4
            Call RandomNumberGenerator()
            'Cardslots Player1
            If CardTypeArray(StartHands) = "" Then
                If DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0) > 0 Then
                    DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0) -= 1
                    Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0) += 1
                    CardCheckBoxArray(StartHands).Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                    CardTypeArray(StartHands) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                    Me.NumberArray(StartHands) = Number
                Else
                    'Recall Procedure if Generated Random Number is not allowed due to QuantityInteger <= 0
                    Call StartButton_Click(sender, e)
                End If
            End If
        Next StartHands
```

These are the major pieces of the code that have relevance to this. I included the event procedure portion to show which procedures each piece belongs to.

Comment: Something like `Player(1).HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0)`? I also suggest replacing `QuantityInteger` with something more meaningful.

Comment: Thank you again Neolisk. I figured it out myself shortly after posting this. I can't believe I never knew I could do this before. This will probably cut all the code in my program by 30-40%...

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote some answers in that other question as well.

Comment: All I did was change the quantityinteger to quantityinteger(0) just to test it, and now I have to debug a stack overflow. Fun...

Comment: You need to also change the type from `Integer` to a list of `Integer`, or an array, depends on further usage, and modify all relevant calls. Suggestion would be to add `Option Strict On` - it should catch these kind of errors for you.

Comment: Yup already had Option Strict On the entire time.


Operator '-' is not defined for types 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)' and 'Integer'. 

is one of the error messages I gained when switching it to list(of integer)

Comment: Another suggestion - post the relevant parts of your code into your question above. We'll see if possible to help.

Comment: Now I'm getting nullreference...

Dim is how it should be declared in the structure group correct?

Comment: `Dim` is one of the options, yes. You may need to initialize before using (i.e. `Dim variable As New Class` or `variable = New Class`).

Comment: Added the major portions of my code into the question. I'll try to work out what you told me so far.

Comment: Doing `Public QuantityInteger() As Integer` will make the size of array equal zero, so you naturally would get an exception here `QuantityInteger(0)` - calling the first element.